# pass a string to tidybayes::spread_draws()

Tags: r, tidyverse

How could I pass the variable name `typical_r` to `tidybayes::spread_draws()` programmatically? In my use case `typical_r` comes in as a string, but I can't pass a string to `tidybayes::spread_draws()`.

```
library(tidybayes)
library(tidyverse)

data(RankCorr, package = "tidybayes")

RankCorr %>%
  spread_draws(typical_r) # this works

x <- c("typical_r", "tau[1]")

RankCorr %>%
  spread_draws(x[1]) # this does not
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`!!sym()`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rlang/versions/0.2.2/topics/sym) to convert from string into a symbol

```
RankCorr %>%
  spread_draws((!!sym(x[1])))
```